# Support of derived function

Tags: real-analysis

I have a question about support of a differentiable function.

Let $f,g$ be $\mathbb{R}$ valued $C^{1}$-funcitons on $\mathbb{R}$. Suppose that ${\rm supp}[f] \cap {\rm supp}[g]=\emptyset$. where
\begin{align*}
{\rm supp}[f]=\overline{\{x \in \mathbb{R}: f(x) \neq 0\}}
\end{align*} 
**My question**
Can we show ${\rm supp}[f'] \cap {\rm supp}[g']=\emptyset$ ?

**My attempt**

Since $\{x \in \mathbb{R}: f'(x) \neq 0 \} \subset {\rm supp}[f]$, we can get ${\rm supp}[f'] \subset {\rm supp}[f]$. Similarly ${\rm supp}[g'] \subset {\rm supp}[g]$. Since ${\rm supp}[f] \cap {\rm supp}[g]=\emptyset$, we can get ${\rm supp}[f'] \cap {\rm supp}[g']=\emptyset$

Is this correct?

Thank you in advance.

**ADD**: Proof of $\{x \in \mathbb{R}: f'(x) \neq 0 \} \subset {\rm supp}[f]$

Let $a \in \{x \in \mathbb{R}: f'(x) \neq 0 \}$. We can assume that $f'(a)>0$ and by continuity of $f'$ there exists a $b \in \mathbb{R}$ such that $f'(x) \geq \frac{f'(a)}{2}$ on $[b,a]$ and $f'(b)>0$.
Then
\begin{align*}
f(a)=\int_{b}^{a}f'(x)dx+f(b) \geq \frac{f'(a)}{2}(a-b)+f(b)>0
\end{align*}
Therefore $a \in  {\rm supp}[f]$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You still need to give a proof for your claim $\{x \in \mathbb{R} \;|\; f'(x) \ne 0\} \subset \mathrm{supp}[f]$, but aside from this your proof is correct.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. But I don't know how to prove $\{x \in \mathbb{R} : f'(x) \neq 0 \} \subset {\rm supp}[f]$. By drawing a picture, It may be right.

Comment: I supplemented my proof.

Comment: And how do you know that $f(b) \ge 0$? Also, you didn't use that $\mathrm{supp}$ is the closure of $f^1{-1}(\{0\})$, but this is vital to the assertion. Your proof is also unnecessarily complicated. Try showing $\mathrm{supp}[f]^c \subset \mathrm{supp}[f']^c$ instead.

Comment: I apologize for this late reply.　I understood. Thank you!